# Error with tensorflow map_fn. Unable to specify output signature

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor, ragged-tensors

I am trying to use tensorflow's [tf.map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) to map a ragged tensor but I am getting an error that I can't fix.
Here is some minimal code that demonstrates the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.ragged.constant([[0,1,2], [0,1]])
def outer_product(x):
  return x[...,None]*x[None,...]
tf.map_fn(outer_product, X)
```

My desired output is:

```
tf.ragged.constant([
 [[0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 2, 4]],
 [[0, 0],
  [0, 1]]
])
```

The error I am getting is:

> "InvalidArgumentError: All flat_values must have compatible shapes.
> Shape at index 0: [3].  Shape at index 1: [2].  If you are using
> tf.map_fn, then you may need to specify an explicit
> fn_output_signature with appropriate ragged_rank, and/or convert
> output tensors to RaggedTensors. [Op:RaggedTensorFromVariant]"

I realize I need to specify fn_output_signature but despite experimentation, I cannot figure out what it should be.

EDIT: I cleaned up AloneTogether's excellent answer a little bit and created a function that maps ragged tensors. His answer uses the `tf.ragged.stack` function to convert the tensors to ragged tensors which `tf.map_fn` needs for some reason

```
def ragged_map_fn(func, t): 
  def new_func(t):
    return tf.ragged.stack(func(t),0)
  signature = tf.type_spec_from_value(new_func(t[0]))
  ans = tf.map_fn(new_func, t, fn_output_signature=signature)
  ans = tf.squeeze(ans, 1)
  return ans
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ragged tensors are sometimes really tricky. Here is one option you can try out:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.ragged.constant([
                        [0,1,2], 
                        [0,1]
                       ])
def outer_product(x):
  t = x[...,None] * x[None,...]
  return tf.ragged.stack(t)


y = tf.map_fn(outer_product, X, fn_output_signature=tf.RaggedTensorSpec(shape=[1, None, None],
                                                                    dtype=tf.type_spec_from_value(X).dtype,
                                                                    ragged_rank=2,
                                                                    row_splits_dtype=tf.type_spec_from_value(X).row_splits_dtype))
tf.print(y)
#y = tf.concat([y[0, :], y[1, :]], axis=0) # Remove additional dimension from Ragged Tensor
y = y.merge_dims(0, 1)
tf.print(y)
```

```
[
 [
  [
   [0, 0, 0], 
   [0, 1, 2], 
   [0, 2, 4]
  ]
 ], 
 [
  [
   [0, 0], 
   [0, 1]
  ]
 ]
]
```

And after removing the additional dimension with `y.merge_dims(0, 1)` or `tf.concat`:

```
[
 [
  [0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 1, 2], 
  [0, 2, 4]
 ], 
 [
  [0, 0], 
  [0, 1]
 ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I was hoping to understand how you came to this solution. I noticed you added a ragged stack in the outer_product function. Was this because I needed to convert the tensors to ragged tensors? Also I was able to remove `row_splits_dtype=tf.type_spec_from_value(X).row_splits_dtype` and the code still worked is there a reason you included it?

Comment: Yes, indeed, but using `tf.RaggedTensor` would not work, because `tf.map_fn` needs this "extra" dimension.